# Prevent alias from using alias - bash

Tags: unix, alias, bash

I'm currently editing my `.bashrc` and would like a behaviour like this:

- `ls` should execute as `ls -AGlp | grep -v "\->"` (show all files as a coloured list excluding symbolic links).
- `ly` should execute as `ls -AGlp` (same thing, but don't exclude symbolic links).

I added these two lines to my `.bashrc`:

- `alias ls='ls -AGlp | grep -v "\->"'`
- `alias ly='ls -AGlp'`

Sadly the second alias uses the first alias of `ls` and expands to `ls -AGlp | grep -v "\->"' -AGlp`, which results in a *grep*-error.

What can I do about this? I need some way to prevent the seconds alias from using the first alias of `ls` instead of the *regular* command `ls`.

Comment: `alias ly='/usr/bin/ls -AGlp'`

Comment: @redneb That unnecessarily bypasses `PATH` lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `command ls` to use the original `ls`

Comment: What an easy fix. Thank you for the quick answer. I'll accept as soon as possible.